# PLus MInus program in java

Tags: java, arrays

Given an array arr of N integers, Calculate the ratios of its elements that are positive, negative, and zero to the array size N.

Print the decimal value of each fraction in a new line up to 6 decimal places.
Language Java

Input Format
The first line contains an integer N, the size of the array.

The second line contains N space-separated integers representing the array arr.

Output Format
Print the 3 required ratios up to 6 decimal places.

Example 1
Input
6
-4 3 -9 -5 4 1

Output
0.500000
0.500000
0.000000

I wrote the below code for the mentioned program ,
I keep getting the error error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
I declared everything as a double but still getting the error

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double a = sc.nextDouble();
    double b[] = new double[a];
    double c=0,d=0,e=0;
    for(double i=0;i<a;i++){
      b[i]= sc.nextDouble();//your code here
    }
    for(double j=0 ; j<a ;j++){
      if(b[j]>0){
        c++;
      }
      else if(b[j]<0){
        d++;
      }
      else{
        e++;
      }
    } 

    System.out.println(String.format(" %.6f",(c/a)));
     System.out.println(String.format(" %.6f",(d/a)));
     System.out.println(String.format(" %.6f",(e/a)));
}}
```

Comment: Should you use your `c`, `d`, `e` counters as `int` instead of `double`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use `a`, `i` and `j` as indices of the array `b`, but you are not allowed to use a double variable as an index in java, you have to use integers. You can use `Math.floor()` to convert the doubles to ints